# Using jQuery to insert a Google Map Iframe into a Div

Tags: jquery, google-maps, iframe

I am trying to use jQuery to add a Google Map Iframe to my HTML webpage. I am able to use it when I simply hard code it into my HTML however I am using jQuery to create and format all of the HTML and content.

This static HTML works correctly:

> ```
> <iframe width="450"
>         height="250"
>         frameborder="0" style="border:0"
>         src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key={MY_KEY}&center={LATITUDE,LONGITUDE}&zoom=4&maptype=satellite"></iframe>
> ```

However if I try and do the same thing in jQuery it will only display the border.

jQuery code:

```
$('.hiddenDiv').append('<iframe frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key={MY_KEY}&center={LATITUDE,LONGITUDE}&zoom=4&maptype=satellite"></iframe>');
```

I am passing the values of Latitude and Longitude into the iframe, but even when I hard code these values, the same issue occurs. If I look at the elements of the webpage once it has been loaded I can see the google maps iframe and the corresponding elements that it pulls in from google. Though nothing other than the border is visibly displayed.

**Edit**

I think it has something to do with me inserting the map into a hidden Div (Display:none). If I insert it into any other divs that are not hidden then it works as expected. I am also using jQuery to toggle this hidden Div to display it's contents.

Any help would be great.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try it this way.

```
$('<iframe />', {
    name: 'myFrame',
    id:   'myFrame',
    src: 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key={MY_KEY}&center={LATITUDE,LONGITUDE}&zoom=4&maptype=satellite'
}).appendTo('.hiddenDiv');
```

I'd like to know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Na that doesn't work either same issue as before, it displays the border and that is it. If I enter the key wrong then it will display text in the iframe saying that it was an invalid key. So I am not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Okay so I think it might have something to do with me putting it in a div that is hidden, (display:none). If i use divs that are not hidden then it displays correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/179/
JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.hiddenDiv').show('fast', function () {
            $(this).append('<iframe frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?output=embed&iwloc&z=12&t=p&q=Bangalore India"></iframe>');
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

CSS:

```
.hiddenDiv {
    display:none;
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
}
iframe {
    height:inherit;
    width:inherit;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="hiddenDiv"></div>
```

**Note:** I changed the `src` of iframe for testing purpose and also used a `setTimeout` for the same. But the logic remains the same.